# All except one module doesn't load in lazy loading

Tags: angular

I wrote the below code for lazyloading. All the modules except EmployerModule load well when I go to their corresponding routes. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./login/login.module').then((c) => c.LoginModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./login/home.module').then((c) => c.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'employer',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./employer/employer.module').then((c) => c.EmployerModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: How did you arrive at conclusion that this module is not loading as expected and others are!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading routes example might be helpful.

[Click Here..](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-lazy-loading)